# How to set the content area of admin panel to occupy the remaining width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this html, a simple skeleton for admin panel:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.adminpanel {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.leftpane {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #0038a8;
}    

.rightpane {
  width: 87%;
  background-color: #ce1126;
}
```

```html
<div class="adminpanel">
  <div class="leftpane">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="rightpane">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

From the code above, I set `.leftpane` to have a width of 250px. How do I set the `.rightpane` to occupy the remaining width?

Using `width: 87%;` works on my laptop width with a 1900px resolution.

Any ideas?

I work on admin panel before but with css framework, which is not in this case.

Comment: .rightpane {flex: 1}

Comment: as a side note, you need to consider the related question you get while writing yours .. they are aslo visible in the right side of this question actually .. 2 of these questions answer perfectly yours

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`flex-grow:1;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) on the right pane and remove the width:

```css
.adminpanel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}

.leftpane {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #0038a8;
}

.rightpane {
  background-color: #ce1126;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="adminpanel">
  <div class="leftpane">
    left
  </div>

  <div class="rightpane">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
.rightpane { flex-grow: 1; }
```

Or the old school:

```
.rightpane { width: calc(100% - 250px); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {margin: 0}

.adminpanel {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.leftpane {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #0038a8;
}    

.rightpane {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*or width: calc(100% - 250px)     */
  background-color: #ce1126;
}
```

```html
<div class="adminpanel">
  <div class="leftpane">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="rightpane">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```